# hackerrank average function in python

Tags: python, function, average

hi guys i tried runnig this code bit it keeps failing at most of the test i don't what the problem is!!

```
#!/bin/python

import math
import os
import random
import re
import sys


# write your code here
def avg(*num):
    if len(num)==0:
        return None
    sum=0
    for i in num:
        sum=sum+i
        moy=sum/len(num)
    return(moy)

    

if __name__ == '__main__':
    fptr = open(os.environ['OUTPUT_PATH'], 'w')
    
    nums = map(int, raw_input().split())
    res = avg(*nums)
    
    fptr.write('%.2f' % res + '\n')

    fptr.close()
```

Comment: You might also wanna use `float` instead of `int` to ensure your avg will be a float regardless of the python version.

Comment: Indeed, judging from the `raw_input` this is Python 2, where `/` on ints is floor-division.

Answer (score 3):

There are a few corrections you can consider while coding:

1. `sum=0` - you are using [`sum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum) which is an inbuilt function of Python.
   Not an efficient way of coding to use pre-defined names.
2. `moy=sum/len(num)` - this line is wasting a lot of time of Python compiler as you are asking it to perform computation right from the first iteration till last, where only the last iteration when sum of all numbers is calculated is needed to find the average.
3. `moy=sum/len(num)` - The standard division symbol (`/`) operates differently in Python 3 and Python 2 when applied to integers.

   When dividing an integer by another integer in Python 3, the division operation `x / y` represents a true division (uses `__truediv__` method) and produces a floating-point result. Meanwhile, the same operation in Python 2 represents a classic division that rounds the result down toward negative infinity (also known as taking the floor).

   Meaning, `5/2` in Python2 would be `2.00` while in Python3 would be `2.50`.

   It's better to typecast: `float()` - This function is used to convert any data type to a floating-point number.

Fixed code:

```
def avg(*num):
    if len(num)==0:
        return None
    sum_num=0
    for i in num:
        sum_num += i
    return(float(sum_num)/len(num))
```

Answer (score 3):

```
def avg(*nums):
    return sum(nums)/len(nums)
```

Use this function instead.

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392712/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes for you. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please edit your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/python

import math
import os
import random
import re
import sys


# write your code here
def avg(*num):
    if len(num)==0:
        return None
    sum=0
    for i in num:
        sum=sum+i
        moy=sum/len(num)
    return(moy)

    

if __name__ == '__main__':
    fptr = open(os.environ['OUTPUT_PATH'], 'w')
    
    nums = map(int, raw_input().split())
    res = avg(*nums)
    
    fptr.write('%.2f' % res + '\n')

    fptr.close()
```

Comment: Did you find your error and want to self-answer? Then please highlight what you changed. Or is this supposed to be an update? Then please use the `edit` link under the question.

Comment: This function calculates the average of 2 and 5 as 3 instead of 3.5. It's wrong. Change the function with the answer above for the correct result.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
for i in num:
```

Use this:

```
for i in nums:
```

and your code will work.

Answer (score 0):

I passed this code through my hackerrank test with python 3.

```
#!/bin/python3

import math
import os
import random
import re
import sys

def avg(*arg):
    return (sum(arg)/len(arg))

# write your code here
if __name__ == '__main__':
    fptr = open(os.environ['OUTPUT_PATH'], 'w')
    
    nums = list(map(int, input().split()))
    res = avg(*nums)
    
    fptr.write('%.2f' % res + '\n')

    fptr.close()
```